# Cannot run my script from my GitHub repository using Travic CI: Import error

Tags: python, travis-ci

Travis CI isn't working. SSW-567 is my main directory and it has a folder HW02, which has a folder HW02a inside it. I have my python file named TestTriangle.py that resides inside SSW-567>HW02>HW02a>TestTriangle.py.

My .travis.ci file contains:

```
language: python
python:
 - "3.7.1"

# command to run tests
script:
 - python -m unittest /tree/master/HW02/HW02a/TestTriangle
```

and it resides inside SSW-567 (my main repository)

Why is it giving me ImportError?

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet of the full trace back

Answer (score 1):

Travis CI runs python from the root of the directory, where your travis.yml file is.

So it should be

```
script:
 - python -m unittest HW02/HW02a/TestTriangle
```

Check out [the simplejson travis.yml file for an example of referring to a file in the git repo](https://github.com/simplejson/simplejson/blob/6cbbd1859f7ff219c19f68d3063842cdd6db1885/.travis.yml#L40).